# How to set all labels of all entity forms according to a simple rule

Tags: php, forms, symfony

for all the entity forms of my Symfony2 app, I'd like all labels to be of the following form: `<entity_name>.<field_name>`
Having the possibility to change the label afterwards would be cool.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default label's behavior is defined in the `FieldType`:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FieldType.php#L55

*(note: the FieldType class was deprecated in Symfony 2.1 and removed in Symfony 2.3)*

If you want to change the default type's behavior, you can create an extension:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/AbstractTypeExtension.php

```
class FieldTypeEntityLabelExtension
{
    static $currentTypeName;
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $types = $builder->getTypes();

        $type = end($types);

        $dataClass   = get_class($type);
        if (strpos($dataClass, 'Uc') === 0) // <-- My namespace
        {
            $classParts              = explode( '\\', $dataClass);
            $translationParts        = array_slice($classParts, 3);
            self::$currentTypeName   = implode('.', array_map('Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::underscore', $translationParts));
        }

        if (isset(self::$currentTypeName) && !$options['precious'])
        {
            $builder->setAttribute('label', sprintf('%s.%s', substr(self::$currentTypeName, 0, -5), $builder->getName()));
        }
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'field';
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice. I'll try that on Monday. +1

Comment: Works like a charm! Jackpot for you! I added an implementation, it is a bit ugly (I use a static variable to store the entity name), but maybe you have a better idea?

Comment: Maybe you can try to do something based on your Type's name instead of the entity name.

Comment: True, a form necessarily bound to an entity... I think I'll change that when I have the time.

Comment: Here... a solution with the type. It looks slightly better.